# Map value to item from list and add the new value to the same list C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have an Array of colors viz.

```
var colorPallete = new string[]{color1, color2, color3, color4, color5};
```

I also have a list of objects which contains an ID.
eg. `var previousList<MyModel>  = new List<MyModel>();`

MyModel.cs

```
public class MyModel()
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
public string Class{get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

I want to assign the objects with same ID with a certain color. And then add the assigned color as a new value to the list.

for eg:

Previous list :-

```
            ID :1
            Name: abc
            Class: Senior

           ID :2
            Name: xyz
            Class: Medium

            ID :3
            Name: pqr
            Class: junior

           ID :1
            Name: mno
            Class: junior
```

New List :-

```
            ID :1
            Name: abc
            Class: Senior
            Color :color1

            ID :2
            Name: xyz
            Class: Medium
            Color :color2

            ID :3
            Name: pqr
            Class: junior
            Color :color3

            ID :1
            Name: mno
            Class: junior
            Color :color1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `List<T>` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) and you don't want to create a new list, but need to update values in the existing list instead, you can do it with the single query. There are three ways to process your scenario (A, B, C):

```
var colorPallete = new string[]
{
    "Red", "Green", "Blue"
};

var list = new List<MyModel>()
{
    new MyModel() { ID = 1, Name = "model1", Class = "A", },
        new MyModel() { ID = 1, Name = "model11", Class = "AA", },
        new MyModel() { ID = 2, Name = "model2", Class = "B", },
        new MyModel() { ID = 3, Name = "model3", Class = "C", },                            
        new MyModel() { ID = 4, Name = "model4", Class = "D", },
        new MyModel() { ID = 5, Name = "model5", Class = "E", },            
};

//A. This code assigns null for unknown IDs
//I.e. if (ID > 0 && ID < colorPallete.Length) then color will be picked from colorPallete[],
//else it will be null
list.ForEach(x => x.Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault(x.ID - 1));

//B. This code apply some default color for unknown IDs
//I.e. if (ID > 0 && ID < colorPallete.Length) then color will be picked from colorPallete,
//else it will be "DefaultColor"
list.ForEach(x => x.Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault(x.ID - 1) ?? "DefaultColor");

//C. This code can assign the same color to models with different IDs, 
//but models with identical IDs always will have identical color
list.ForEach(x => x.Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault((x.ID - 1) % colorPallete.Length));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach but I get the color null. Also, I have a fixed array of colors where as the ID's in the list can be more than the number of colors

Comment: @helloworld Hi, I've updated my answer to meet your requirements. There are three ways to process your scenario. May be I still misunderstood something. If so, feel free to inform me. You can play with my code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/22OJOC)

Comment: Thanks for your example on Fiddle. Helped me get a better picture. 3rd approach was exactly what I was looking for.Accepting your answer. Have a  nice day

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
var colorPallete = new string[]
{
    "color1", "color2", "color3", "color4", "color5",
};

var previousList = new []
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "abc", Class = "Senior", },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "xyz", Class = "Medium", },
    new { ID = 3, Name = "pqr", Class = "junior", },
    new { ID = 1, Name = "mno", Class = "junior", },
};

var newList =
    previousList
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.Name,
            x.Class,
            Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault(x.ID - 1),
        })
        .ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

---

With the question update providing the class `MyModel` the code can then be written like so:

```
var colorPallete = new string[]
{
    "color1", "color2", "color3", "color4", "color5",
};

var previousList = new List<MyModel>()
{
    new MyModel() { ID = 1, Name = "abc", Class = "Senior", },
    new MyModel() { ID = 2, Name = "xyz", Class = "Medium", },
    new MyModel() { ID = 3, Name = "pqr", Class = "junior", },
    new MyModel() { ID = 1, Name = "mno", Class = "junior", },
};

var newList =
    previousList
        .Select(x => new MyModel()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            Class = x.Class,
            Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault(x.ID - 1),
        })
        .ToList();
```

Which gives:

[image: MyModel result]

Now, this approach produces a new list keeping the old list and the old objects intact. Generally this is what you should try to do. It's best to mutate objects only when you know that's what they're designed to do.

So it becomes possible to do an in-place update of the original list like so:

```
previousList.ForEach(x => x.Color = colorPallete.ElementAtOrDefault(x.ID - 1));
```

This results in modifying the `previousList` objects without creating a `newList`.

Comment: This gives me an error `Cannot implicitly convert type '.List<AnonymousType#1>' to '.List<mymodel>'`

Comment: @helloworld - That would be expected. When you post your question you need to give all object models used. It's shouldn't be too hard for you to adapt, but I'm happy to update my answer if you post your class definition in your question. Can you post both types for `previousList` and `newList`?

Comment: I have edited my question. previousList and newList should be of type List<MyModel>

Comment: @helloworld - you're not able to use the same type for both lists of you're adding a field. How does `Color` fit in?

Comment: Pl see my edited question. I have added another property in my MyModel class. Will that Help?

Comment: @helloworld - I've updated my answer. There are now three approaches, with the latter two focusing on `MyModel`.

Comment: I tried this approach. But i get the color as null.

Comment: @helloworld - Then you haven't properly followed my code. It works when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for the objects with a color property like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; } // Nullable
}
```

And for the colors I would create another class with an ID to compare with the ID of `MyClass`:

```
public class MyColor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

For each color in colorPalette you would assign an ID that matches the ID of the list of `MyClass`.

So at first the color from MyClass would be null. And then you could loop over the list of `MyClass`:

```
foreach (MyClass myClass in myClassList)
{
    myClass.Color = colorPalette.FirstOrDefault(col => col.ID = myClass.ID);
}
```

Or without an ID in `Color` class (comparing the names of the variables which is not a beautiful solution):

```
foreach (MyClass myClass in myClassList)
{
    myClass.Color = colorPalette.FirstOrDefault(col => int.Parse(nameof(col.Color).Replace("color", "")) == myClass.ID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What is colors here?

Comment: Edited my answer. `colors` should be `colorPalette`, sorry for this.

Comment: Thanks. I can still not get col.ID . I think Im missing something. Could you please post how can I get col.ID.

Comment: Added the class `MyColor` to the answer.

Comment: umm my colors are strings. So should there be string instead of Color? Pardon me iam new to C#

Comment: Oh, sure. I changed the colors to string.

Comment: I did this
`foreach (var m in myList)
                    {
                        m.Color = colorPallete.FirstOrDefault(col => col.ID = m.Id);
                    }` . But it gives me an error at col.ID saying  'string' does not contain a definition of 'ID' accepting the first argument string

Comment: How does col fit in?